# Tuesday's Unmatched Donimoes Problem

Tags: sliding-blocks, dominoes

I've designed a set of dominoes puzzles that I call [Donimoes](https://donkirkby.github.io/donimoes/). You slide the
dominoes like the cars in Nob Yoshigahara's Rush Hour puzzle, always along
their long axis. The goal of Unmatched Donimoes is to slide all the dominoes
into a rectangle, without sliding any matching numbers next to each other. See
[Monday's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86423/38) problem for complete rules and and an example solution.

Today's problem is a little bigger and a little harder. Good luck, and post
your solution as an answer.

[image: starting position]

If you like this puzzle, watch for new problems every day this week.

Comment: I think I have a solution, but how in the world do I recreate that image? Did you use a certain software or what?

Comment: I wrote a Python program, @Cubemaster, and you could [download it](https://github.com/donkirkby/donimoes/blob/master/svg_diagram.py). It's probably not worth the effort, though, when you can just list the moves as I did in Monday's example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following would work

> 25R 03R 42R 34R 25R 03R 42R 34R 25R 03R 42R 34R 05R 25R 03R 42R 34R 05R 25R 33D

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to do this visually, but I think the solution is:

> 25R, 03R, 42R, 34R, 25R, 03R, 42R, 05R, 34R, 25R, 03R, 42R, 34R, 05R, 33D

For a total of 15 moves

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think your first move is disallowed. "All the dominoes in the puzzle have to be connected in one solid group, diagonal connections don’t count."

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice that part. Makes it slightly more complicated

Comment: There we go, should be better now

Comment: you're missing five moves: it doesn't end being a rectangle

Comment: Remember, each move moves a domino **one space** along its long axis. Were you moving more than one space at a time in some of those moves?