# Wednesday's Unmatched Donimoes Problem

Tags: sliding-blocks, dominoes

I've designed a set of dominoes puzzles that I call [Donimoes](https://donkirkby.github.io/donimoes/). You slide the
dominoes like the cars in Nob Yoshigahara's Rush Hour puzzle, always along
their long axis. The goal of Unmatched Donimoes is to slide all the dominoes
into a rectangle, without sliding any matching numbers next to each other. See
[Monday's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86423/38) problem for complete rules and and an example solution. [Tuesday's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86452/38)
problem would make a good warmup.

Today's problem is a little bigger and a little harder. Good luck, and post
your solution as an answer.

[image: starting position]

If you like this puzzle, watch for new problems every day this week.

Comment: Is there a limit to how far the dominoes can slide?  i.e. Is there a bounding box?  If not, it should be trivial in most cases just to slide all the dominoes out into the surrounding area until there is ample space between them all, and then they can easily be rearranged into any configuration  you like without running afoul of other dominoes.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain  "All the dominoes in the puzzle have to be connected in one solid group, diagonal connections don’t count." So the dominoes must form a contiguous set at all times.

Comment: @hexomino Thanks. I guess I should have looked at the complete rules before posting questions that have already been answered....

Comment: After I designed the rules, @OmegaKrypton, I found it hard to design new problems. I wrote a computer program that uses evolutionary search to find interesting problems. You can read my [making Donimoes](http://donkirkby.github.io/donimoes/making_donimoes.html) post, if you want more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The first order of business is to slide the 12 domino out of the way so that we can slide the 13 domino to the right:
>
> 22UU, 16UU, 34RR, 00DD, 25R, 45R, 12D, 13RR
>
> That having been done, we can now push everything else from the centre back where it came from:
>
> 12U, 45L, 25L, 00UU, 34LL
>
> and then form a rectangle:
>
> 16D, 22D, 03U, 14U
>
> and the puzzle is solved (assuming I haven't made any mistakes, which may well be the case given that I don't have a set of dominoes with me).

Comment: Nice answer! I like your compressed notation when a domino moves twice.