# Thursday's Unmatched Donimoes Problem

Tags: sliding-blocks, dominoes

I've designed a set of dominoes puzzles that I call [Donimoes](https://donkirkby.github.io/donimoes/). You slide the
dominoes like the cars in Nob Yoshigahara's Rush Hour puzzle, always along
their long axis. The goal of Unmatched Donimoes is to slide all the dominoes
into a rectangle, without sliding any matching numbers next to each other. See
[Monday's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86423/38) problem for complete rules and and an example solution. [Tuesday's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86452/38)
and [Wednesday's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86499/38) problems would make a good warmup.

Today's problem is a little bigger and a little harder. Good luck, and post
your solution as an answer.

[image: starting layout]

If you like this puzzle, watch for one more problem tomorrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seemed to work. There are a couple of spots where there are disconnected pieces during a move, but IIRC that was acceptable.

> [image]

Comment: The animated gif is cute. I found [gif-scrubber](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gif-scrubber/gbdacbnhlfdlllckelpdkgeklfjfgcmp?hl=en) to help me step through it for checking the moves.