# Fridays's Unmatched Donimoes Problem

Tags: sliding-blocks, dominoes

I've designed a set of dominoes puzzles that I call [Donimoes](https://donkirkby.github.io/donimoes/). You slide the
dominoes like the cars in Nob Yoshigahara's Rush Hour puzzle, always along
their long axis. The goal is to slide all the dominoes into a rectangle,
without sliding any matching numbers next to each other. See [Monday's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86423/38) problem
for complete rules and and an example solution. [Tuesday's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86452/38), [Wednesday's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86499/38), and
[Thursday's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86541/38) problems would make a good warmup.

Today's problem is the grand finale, using a complete set of double-six dominoes!
Good luck, and post your solution as an answer.

[image: starting layout]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was tricky! (The top right corner is particularly difficult to manoeuvre, avoiding putting the 2's and 1's together. The 0's and 1's at the bottom also pose similar problems...)

A winning set of moves is as follows (move sets in brackets can be carried out in more than one order):

> 24U, 00U, [54L, 05L, 14U, 21U,] 02L, 02L, 02L, [21D, 35D, 14D, 26D,] 22R, 04R, 51D, 51D, 51D, [04L, 65L, 22L,] 26U, 03L, 14U, 21U, 02R, 05R, 54R, 00D, 24D, 35U, 02R, 02R, 21D, 14D, 65L, 03L, 16L, 16L, [26U, 35U, 14U, 21U,] 02L, 02L, 64U, 64U, 43R, 06R, 01R, 11R, 66R, 13R, 63D, 52D, 44D.

In diagram form (read along each row):

> [image]

56 moves in total!

Comment: Congratulations, @Stiv! Thanks to everyone who tried out my Donimoes puzzles this week.